# Função Random.getstate Python

Tags: python-2.7, random

Preciso da ajuda de vocês na seguinte situação:

- Possuo um loop que a cada interação é gerado um valor aleatório de 0 a 400.
- Preciso que minha função retorne em qual momento do loop foi gerado o número X. (Por exemplo, no loop 4 foi gerado o número 15 e etc...)
- Não posto nenhum código de exemplo, por que não sei como fazer isso.
- No meus estudos, vi que existe a função **random.getstate** e **random.setstate**, porém não sei como usá-las ou se existe uma solução melhor que elas.

Peço a ajuda de vocês.

Desde já grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito é disso que você precisa:

```
from random import randint

tamanholoop=10

for i in xrange(tamanholoop):
    print "Posicao " + str(i)
    print "Randomico "+ str(randint(0,400))
```

O Resultado é algo assim:

```
C:\Python27>python randon.py
Posicao 0
Randomico 56
Posicao 1
Randomico 58
Posicao 2
Randomico 287
Posicao 3
Randomico 374
Posicao 4
Randomico 134
Posicao 5
Randomico 332
Posicao 6
Randomico 94
Posicao 7
Randomico 291
Posicao 8
Randomico 228
Posicao 9
Randomico 325
```

É só imprimir a posição do loop e logo abaixo imprimir o valor randômico pego na função `randint` no intervalo que você precisa!

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente isso que precisava.

Muito Obrigado.

Grande abraço.